# Android RxJava2 Handle Orientation Changed

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, reactive

I'm new at this library, so if you got any tips or suggestions are more than welcome.
I got RxJava2 running and executing a longNetworkOperation fake method, the flow is this:

- Create the observable:  Observable.just("str1")
- Change the execution thread: .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
- Implement the map interface which will execute the LongRunningProcess:

  ```
  .map(new Function<String, String>() { 
       @Override
       public String apply(String cad){ // cad is the input value
              Log.d(TAG,"long operation in thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()); //output thread name
              return " longNetworkOperation result => "+doLongNetworkOperation(); //here we do the background operations
              }})
  ```
- Get the results in Main Thread: .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
- Add the observer which get notified for the results: .subscribe(observer);

And the observer:

```
 Observer observer = new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) { Log.d(TAG,"onSubscribe, thread name >> "+Thread.currentThread().getName()); }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Object value) { Log.d(TAG,"on next, input value:<<"+value.toString()+">>  thread name >>"+Thread.currentThread().getName());}

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) { Log.d(TAG,"error >>"+e.toString()); }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.d(TAG,"onCompleted  thread name >> "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        tvRxJava = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_rxjava); //update the reference of tvRxJava.
        tvRxJava.setText("process executed..."); //this line does not change the value of the TextView tvRxJava.
    }
};
```

This works fine, with no device rotation, but if you rotate the device while doLongNetworkOperation is running in the background the TextView tvRxJava does not update value.
not even with a new inject.

```
tvRxJava = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_rxjava);
```

How do you manage orientation change in android with RxJava2??

This is my gradle dep:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.5'//rxjava2
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1' //rxjava2 for android
```

Comment: The issue is not really with RxJava, it's to do with the fact that when the device orientation changes the default action is to destroy and recreate the Activity. The newly created copy of  the Activity has no way of receiving data from the RxJava request you created in the old activity. You may be able to avoid this by setting appropriate options in the manifest to allow the activity to handle the orientation change itself, which prevents the Activity being destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would like to have cache mechanism for the observable in order to get back the result again in case of configuration changes (which forces activity recreation).
I am sharing two very good article which will give you very clear picture, in order to solve this problem.

1. [First](http://blog.bradcampbell.nz/rxjava-handling-configuration-changes-with-request-observables/)
2. [Second](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/a-mvp-approach-to-lifecycle-safe-requests-with-retrofit-20-and-rxjava)

I am currently following the second approach in my application.

Comment: You're right.. a singleton would allow me to resolve this problem..
And even more with a MVP pattern...   I just thought, RxJava would had some other more elegant solution.  
Thank you.

Comment: @Arpit I have a question. I have asyncTask is running and before completing user changes from Portrait to landscape. I don't want to start new AsynTask() and also i am getting back some response from server that I want to pass to activity. Note: I don't want to use below approaches android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" or onConfigurationChanged. How can I pass data from onPostExecute to new created Activity. Can I solve it by using MVP ? Is it possible without using Fragment? Please help or any kind of lead would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: There are lots of way to do this, you can have a look at viewModal approach suggested by Google.

Comment: Probably, your preferred solution will always be a mystery for us. Links are broken ))